# Splitting code quality reports between Java and JavaScript

Tags: split, sonarqube, test-reporting

Currently SonarQube shows Java and JavaScript code quality metrics under a one report. It would be nice if it shows separately from each other.

Which kind of method should I use for splitting from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multi-language projects, the only information for which you can have the distribution by language is the lines of code. You can see this in the "Size" widget. But for the other metrics, this is not possible (yet).

Comment: Thanks Fabrice for answer. Nearly, 5,6 days I'm searching answer. Sonar shows me: Unit Tests Coverage-70.7% 
Line Coverage-73.6%  Branch Coverage-54.7%.  Problem is Unit Test Coverage-70.7% (Java & JavaScript) but I want to see Java and JavaScript separatly. Another question apears: can we use some kind of tricks like: *.js and *.java test separatly by extensions.

Comment: Also, about first answer, thanks. Sonar shows: Java-5492 lines 
JavaScript-2040 lines.